# Express: Prevent bodyParser from parsing request

Tags: json, node.js, express

I am using Nodejs + Express version 4.14.0 like this:

```
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use( bodyParser.json() );       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
    extended: true
}));
```

This is needed and works as expected. However, for some requests I would like to force the application to not automatically parse the request to json but leave it as plain text, i.e. something like:

```
app.post('/myRequest', function (req.asPlainText(), res) {
    // req is not parsed to json now
});
```

Does anyone know how I can achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass a string as the first argument to `app.use()` and it will only apply the middleware to paths that match. The documentation can be found at http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.use.

An example:

```
app.use('/', bodyParser.json())
```

You could also declare any routes that do not need body-parser prior to adding it as a global middleware, but it is generally a good idea to only use body-parser where you actually need the body.

If you don't want to use app.use() for each route, you can also pass the middleware in the route declaration like:

```
app.post('/', bodyParser.json(), function(req, res) {
  // handle route here
})
```

To not use it for certain routes, just don't include it in the route.

Comment: Thank you for all the variants you presented! Fixed my problem! It is worth mentioning though that I had to it both for app.use( bodyParser.json() ); and app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true }));

Answer (score 1):

create a variable with form.serialize and include result as parameter. 
      `var req = document.forms[0].serialize();
      app.post('/myRequest', req, res) {
        // req is not parsed to json now
      });`

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for something similar to this as I needed the raw body to be passed for a Stripe Webhook signature to work.
I found my answer at [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64557085/nodejs-bodyparser-raw-on-one-route#:~:text=0-,bodyParser.,add%20any%20other%20custom%20middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64557085/nodejs-bodyparser-raw-on-one-route#:%7E:text=0-,bodyParser.,add%20any%20other%20custom%20middleware) which gives you the best of both worlds.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34677953)