# Nodejs bodyParser.raw on one route

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

I have the following in my index.js:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

But Stripe webhooks want this:

> Match the raw body to content type application/json

If I change my index.js to the following:

```
app.use(bodyParser.raw({type: 'application/json'}));
```

It works fine. But all my other API routes will not work anymore. Here is my route:

```
router.route('/stripe-events')
  .post(odoraCtrl.stripeEvents)
```

How can I change to the raw body for only this api route?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can access to both at the same time by doing this:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({
  verify: (req, res, buf) => {
    req.rawBody = buf
  }
}))
```

Now the raw body is available on **req.rawBody** and the JSON parsed data is available on **req.body**.

Answer (score 1):

Divide them into two routers '/api' and '/stripe-events' and indicate `bodyParser.json()` only for the first one:

stripeEvents.js

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
...
router.route('/stripe-events')
  .post(odoraCtrl.stripeEvents)
module.exports = router
```

api.js

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
...
router.route('/resource1')
  .post(addResource1)
router.route('/resource2')
  .post(addResource2)
module.exports = router
```

```
const stripeEventsRouter = require('./routers/stripeEvents';
const apiRouter = require('./routers/api';

apiRouter.use(bodyParser.json());
stripeEventsRouter.use(bodyParser.raw({type: 'application/json'}));
app.use('/api', stripeEventsRouter);
app.use('/api', apiRouter);
```

Comment: What do you mean by `apiRouter` and `stripeEventsRouter`? Would you please give an example?

Comment: added examples to my answer

Answer (score 1):

[`bodyParser.raw()` returns a middleware function](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserrawoptions). Instead of passing it to `app.use()`, simply add the return value as an input parameter before the route handler function for a single route like you would add any other custom middleware.

```
const matchRawBodyToJSON = bodyParser.raw({type: 'application/json'});

router.route( '/stripe-events' )
  .post( matchRawBodyToJSON, odoraCtrl.stripeEvents )
```

Answer (score 0):

The same need here,
My solution was:
use a router for every normal API, and one separate single post handler, with different configurations.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const baseRouter= express.Router();
baseRouter.route('/your_api_route').get(your_function);
baseRouter.route('/your_api_route2').post(your_function2);
baseRouter.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
baseRouter.use(bodyParser.json());

const app = express();
app.use("/", baseRouter)
.post('/webhook', express.raw({type: 'application/json'}),webhook) //this is a special route for stripe webhook (in my case)
+.listen(...
```